# Add leading zeros to a string without zfill, format, loops or control statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to add leading zeros to a string of variable length - to always fit a certain length. And I have to use very simple python without control structures such as `if` statements or `while`/`for`loops. It can be hard coded.

E.g.

```py
    rannum = random.randrange(1, 999)
    zero = "000"
    rannumformat = (zero[0] + str(rannum))
    print(rannumformat)
```

Do I need to use `len()` function as well?

Comment: Why can't you use zfill or format?

Comment: Do you want this string to be a specific length?

Comment: You do not need to use `len` to *add* a leading zero to a string.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I need 9 to be represented as 0009.

Comment: I have to use simple 'linear' methods using len(), concatenation and ranges. Unfortunately a bit annoying without loops.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for you here.

The following script will add a number of leading zeros to the string representation of your random number, always ensuring that it is 3 characters long.

```py
import random;

rannum = random.randrange(1, 999)
rannumStr = str(rannum);

for x in range(len(rannumStr), 3):
    rannumStr = "0" + rannumStr;
print(rannumStr);
```

In case you want the string longer, just update the second parameter of the `range(...)` function, like this for 4 characters:

```py
for x in range(len(rannumStr), 4):
```

### Solution without control statements

Based on the comments, I am adding another answer here. This ones does not use any loops, or other control statements like `if`.

It declares an array of strings, that we can index into using the length of the string representation of the random number. And simply prefix the string with that.

```py
import random;

rannum = random.randrange(1, 999)
rannumStr = str(rannum);

padding = ["000", "00", "0", ""];

rannumStr = padding[len(rannumStr)] + rannumStr;

print(rannumStr);
```

I hope that this solves your issue?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. Is there any change I could do this without conditional loops (the for x in range), as I have to use very simple python to make this. Again thank you very much and have a great day! :D

Comment: Can I use if statements and the len() function?

Comment: I added another solution that does not use loops or if statements. But does make use of the len() function. Let me know if that then can be accepted?

Comment: Yes that is fine. Thank you very much! :D

Comment: I hope this worked out for you? If so, are you able to accept the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If this is "hard coded" to numbers below 10000 and you want 4 total digits, you can simply add 10000 and drop the first character:

```
rannum = random.randrange(1, 999)
print(str(rannum+10000)[1:])
```

or more generally speaking:

```
rannum = random.randrange(1, 999)
digits = 4
print(str(rannum+10**digits)[1:])
```

another (non-numeric) way of doing it could be:

```
rannum = random.randrange(1, 999)
digits = 4
print( ("0"*digits+str(rannum))[-digits:] )

# or hard coded:
print( ("0"*4+str(rannum))[-4:] )
```

and i'm guessing you can't use rjust() either:

```
print( str(rannum).rjust(4,"0") )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :D